# Discord.js Clear command that skips pinned messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to JavaScript and i wanted to make a Discord Bot... I think my discord bot is good but i dont seem to get a command working that clears all messages written in a channel exept the pinned ones...

Can anybody send me a code that works?

Comment: I was searching in the Internet allready but only found garbage

Comment: Did you try something by yourself? Do you have some code you wrote to share? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can bot clear script skip the pinned messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136348/how-can-bot-clear-script-skip-the-pinned-messages)

Answer (score 3):

1. To grab a bulk amount of messages from a channel, use [`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages).
2. To filter through the results to only include messages that aren't pinned, check [`Message.pinned`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=pinned) in a [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) function.
3. To delete all those messages at once, use [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete).<sup>*</sup>

Example:

```js
message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 })
  .then(fetched => {
    const notPinned = fetched.filter(fetchedMsg => !fetchedMsg.pinned);

    message.channel.bulkDelete(notPinned, true);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

[Async/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) equivalent (must be within an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)):

```js
try {
  const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 });
  const notPinned = fetched.filter(fetchedMsg => !fetchedMsg.pinned);

  await message.channel.bulkDelete(notPinned, true);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> *Keep in mind that messages older than 2 weeks cannot be deleted this way. There's also a limit of 2-100 messages per call.*

Answer (score 0):

Since I already answered a quite similar question, I'm just gonna re-use my code.

This way will be slower than using `TextChannel.bulkDelete()`, but will delete message older than 2 weeks.
As slothiful mentionned, calling `Message.delete()` for all those messages is going to impose [rate limits](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits). Discord.js will handle them for you, but you'll definitely notice them.

```js
async function deleteReturnLast(chan, option, prevMsg, cond) {
  return chan.fetchMessages(option)
    .then(async msgs => {
      if (msgs.size === 0){
    if (cond(prevMsg)) {
      prevMsg.delete()
        .then(d => console.log('last message deleted: ' + d.content))
        .catch(err => console.log('ERR>>', err, prevMsg.content, option.before));   }
    return prevMsg;
      };
      let last = msgs.last();
      for (const[id, msg] of msgs) {
    let tmp = (id === last.id) ? prevMsg : msg;
    if (cond(tmp)) {
      tmp.delete()
        .then(d => console.log('Message deleted: ' + d.content))
        .catch(err => console.log('ERR>>', err));
    }
      };
      return last;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('ERR>>', err));
}

function cond(msg) {
  return !msg.pinned;
}

client.on('message', async function(msg) {
  let chan = msg.channel;
  let last = chan.lastMessage;
  while (last !== (last = await deleteReturnLast(chan, {limit: 2, before: last.id}, last, cond))){
  };
});
```