# How do you bulk delete messages excluding the pinned messages?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a script called clear. This script works as intended.

But how can my clear script **skip the pinned messages in the channel**?

This is my script:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    if (message.deletetable) {
        message.delete(); 
    }

    // Member doesn't have permission
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send("You can't delete messages...") // .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    // Check if args[0] is a number
    if (isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
        return message.channel.send("Yeah... That's not a number? I also can't delete 0 messages by the way.") // .then(m => m.delete(5000));

    }

    // Maybe the bot can't delete messages
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send("Sorry... I can't delete messages.") // .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    let deleteAmount;

    if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
        deleteAmount = 100;
    } else {
        deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
        .then(deleted => message.channel.send(`I deleted \`${deleted.size}\` messages.`))
        .catch(err => message.channel.send(`Something went wrong... ${err}`));
}   


module.exports.help = {
  name: "clear"
}
```

I hope someone can help me, because this would be a nice addition to my clear script.

Answer (score 1):

Get all messages of the channel, then pinned messages, do a diff with `filter`, keep only non pinned messages, then delete these ones.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === "/bulk") {
    const allMessages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
    const deletable = allMessages.filter(message => !message.pinned)
    await message.channel.bulkDelete(deletable, true)
  }
});
```

Comment: hi Zooly thanks for your comment.
When I add this code I get this error msg:
`(node:3892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.fetchPinned is not a function`
You can find my pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/LhuSQGFS

Comment: Indeed, it seems that `fetchPinned` is a method of  MessageManager https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetchPinned. I edit my answer

Comment: This is the error I get `(node:33204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: pinnedMessages.includes is not a function`
Editied my pastebin code (same url): https://pastebin.com/LhuSQGFS - thanks for checking Zooly

Comment: It returns a Promise<Collection<Snowflake, Message>>, check how to use includes there. Sorry I can't test right now on my side

Comment: first of all thank you! For checking and helping me ;). When you have time just have a look at it, what my error could mean. I hope you will find the fix. hope to hear from you soon. Grtz

Comment: did you already had the time to check the code yourself? Greetings

Comment: @KevinVerdoodt i've updated my answer with an easier way to achieve the bulk without pinned messages. You have to have discord.js version 12 (11 is not working this way)

Comment: So I deleted everything and started from scratch. I was already in v12 but I followed tutorials from someone that was using version 11...
and I want to thank you Zooly! It worked, thanks for the help man.
Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

While [Zooly’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137019/8289918) works, it doesn’t consider `deleteAmount` — the number of messages the user wants to delete. By default, `MessageManager#fetch` will fetch a maximum 50 messages.

Use the [`limit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) option to fetch the correct number of messages:

```js
await message.channel.bulkDelete(
  // Fetch the messages
  (await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: deleteAmount}))
    // Only include the unpinned messages
    .filter(message => !message.pinned),
  // This parameter (filterOld) ensures that discord.js filters out messages
  // older than 2 weeks before making the request to Discord.
  // Messages older than 2 weeks cannot be deleted with this method and
  // the Discord API will return an error if messages older than 2 weeks are
  // attempted to be bulk deleted.
  true
)
```

Works for discord.js v12 and v13.